# How to set up Tomcat 7 on Synology

Tags: tomcat, synology

I installed Tomcat 7 on Synology DS414. I cannot find any info on how to set it up and get it running. The NAS comes with a Web server app, and that is the one serving up its index.html file. I cannot find any config file for Tomcat, nor can I find any way to enable it, so that it becomes the active web server on the device. Does it replace the Web Station web server that comes with the NAS, or is it an add-on that works with it?

Answer (score 16):

Alvaro is correct.

The correct file is /volume1/@appstore/Tomcat7/src/conf/tomcat-users.xml, edit it using putty or winscp.

Example contents:

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user username="user" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,manager,admin,admin-gui"/>
```

Stop and start the Tomcat package after making changes to the configuration file to make sure Tomcat reloads it.

Comment: What is the command to open the file? It seems that Synology doesn't have nano or any other apps installed.

Comment: You can use vi to open it, however it opens in read-only mode.

Comment: You should use sudo to get root access before the vi command ==>


sudo vi /volume1/@appstore/Tomcat7/src/conf/tomcat-users.xml

Answer (score 9):

When you execute tomcat this will be located on port 7070 by default.

To configure Tomcat7 on synology NAS DS414, you have to access NAS using ssh terminal, the location of the tomcat7 config files are in /volume1/@appstore/Tomcat7/src/conf